# get radio input value wordpress

Tags: php, input, wordpress

I'm using a plugin which retrieves the value of some radio buttons based on what values I type in the plugin dashboard.

I want to change that function with a function which retrieves the post meta of a post as the value.

This is the function for retrieving the post meta :

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'key', true); ?>
```

and this is the actual code for retrieving the values:

```
<?php
/* Radio form */
class ECF_Radio extends ECF_Field_Type {
protected $name = 'radio';

public function form_field( $ref, $field ) {
    global $ecfdb;
    $name = $ecfdb->html_string( $field->name );
    echo "<div class='ecf-form-field-title'>$name</div>\n";
    $values = preg_split( '/, ?/', $field->values );
    echo '<div class=\'ecf-form-field-input\'>';
    foreach ( $values as $i => $value ) {
        $checked = checked( $i, 1, false );
        echo "<p><label><input type='radio' name='$ref' "
            . "value='$value'$checked /> $value</p></label>\n";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}

public function get_description() {
    return "Radio selection field";
}
}

 new ECF_Radio();
 ?>
```

My question is how can I use the function for retrieving the post meta for values?

What exactly do I need to change inside the code to retrieve the post meta not the values written in a filed.

Thank you!

Comment: Off-topic, but I think you need a space before `$checked` in your radio button code: `...value='$value' $checked...`

Comment: Where are you using `ECF_Radio`?

Comment: `ECF_Radio` is used inside the comments area of my website, more exactly it adds two radio inputs based on what values I added from the plugin dashboard, If I added 2 values it retrieves 2 radio inputs with those values...

Comment: or what exactly you mean by where I'm using the ECF_Radio ?

Comment: Where & how does your `ECF_Radio` get called in your code?  All we're seeing here is its definition. (Edit your question to show it, rather than putting it in a comment.)